# for loop counter doesn't increment

Tags: c++

i'm having some issues with this bit of code. basically "k" doesn't increment more than 1. I've already tried to declare it outside the loop but doesn't fix it. basically what the code does is generating a grid of crystals.
this is a uni assessment and at the moment I'am a newbie with console functions, especially managing the cursor. as you can see, at every iteration i add +2 to pos.x. it seems to work, but when it starts again, pos.x returns to the start value and instead is pos.y to increment(?).

```
void gridGeneration(Crystal simbols[][Columns])
{
    COORD pos = {10, 55};

    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        for (int k = 0; k < Columns; k++)
        {
            WriteCrystalAt(simbols[i][k].crystal, pos.X, pos.Y, simbols[i][k].color= rand() % light_yellow + light_blue);

            pos.X += 2; 

            if (k = 1)
            {
                pos.X = 10;
                pos.Y += 2;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: read this line loud 100 times (or until you notice the mistake): `if (k = 1)`

Comment: your compiler should have warned you

Answer (score 4):

It *would* increment further than 1, but you keep setting it to 1 again:

```
if (k = 1)
```

You should use `==` for comparisons.

Your compiler should have issued a warning about this. If it did not, review your warning settings. If it did, stop ignoring warnings.